# How can I set type of arguments in JavaScript for Google closure compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

As you know every function is java script has a variable named 'arguments' in itself that contains all arguments passed to the function.

Consider following code sample:

```
String.prototype.format = function(pattern){

var args = arguments.slice(1);

// other implementations are removed...

}
```

In this scenario, Google Closure Compiler tells me that arguments has no method slice.

As a matter of fact, it has a method names slice, but Google Closure Compiler can not determinate the type of arguments array.

**But at runtime the code works fine**

How can I define the type of arguments for Google Closure Compiler?

What is a best practice?

I've tested several methods, but non of them worked for me.

Without this, our project will not compiled correctly, so we need this, thanks

Thanks

Comment: "But at runtime the code works fine" can not possibly be correct.  Arguments has no "slice" method.  What makes you think it works?

Try it in the console:
  function foobar() {var args = arguments.slice(1)}; foobar();   
Result:
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slice'

Answer (score 3):

`arguments` is not an array (it's an array-like object), so it contains no method `slice`. You can try: `var args = [].slice.call(arguments,1);` In other words, call the `Array.slice`-method for the `arguments`-object to create a real `Array` out of it. To test run this code in a browser console:

```
function foo(){
  console.log([].slice.call(arguments,1));
}
foo(1,2,3); //=> logs [2,3]
```

[**See also**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Comment: Another (more verbose but cleaner) way is: `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)`